# I have a problem in HTML & CSS , hi{ font-family: "impact; } won't change me size off Header Logo .. Thanks

Tags: html, css

https://jsbin.com/hakuzozari/edit?html,css,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<div="header-page">
  <div id="header" class ="container">
  <div id="logo">
    <h1>Header Logo</h1>
    </div>
    </div>  
  <div class="conntent">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/1351534443165528067/1637702650/1500x500" />
  </div>
    </div>
  
  <div id="threeColumns">
  <div id="column1">
    <h2> Column 1</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vulputate et libero at scelerisque. Suspendisse rhoncus tincidunt metus, ut cursus ipsum placerat venenatis. Nullam neque nisl, rhoncus at est quis, faucibus faucibus neque.</p> 
    </div>
    <div id="column2">
    <h2> Column 2</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vulputate et libero at scelerisque. Suspendisse rhoncus tincidunt metus, ut cursus ipsum placerat venenatis. Nullam neque nisl, rhoncus at est quis, faucibus faucibus neque.</p> 
    </div>
    <div id="column3">
    <h2> Column 3</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vulputate et libero at scelerisque. Suspendisse rhoncus tincidunt metus, ut cursus ipsum placerat venenatis. Nullam neque nisl, rhoncus at est quis, faucibus faucibus neque.</p> 
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

hi{   font-family: "impact; }  won't change me size off Header Logo  .. somebody can help me ? thanks

Comment: Typo.  There is no element called `<hi>`.  The element is called `<h1>`.

Answer (score 2):

- Fix the below line (add `class` or `id`), your code doesn't have any `attribute` but a value only:

```
<div id="header-page">
<!-- or -->
<div class="header-page">
<!-- or any other attribute -->
```

- Typo in **CSS** 
  1- `hi` should be `h1` 
  2- `font-weiht` should be `font-weight`

```
h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

- And finally, remember using `semicolon (;)` after every CSS `property: value;` to complete the declaration and allow any other declarations that comes after it.

```
font-family: "impact"; <- Complete this by adding ; to allow the style 
font-weight: normal; <-
```

**The Code**

```css
body{
  background: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #3B3B3B;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "impact";
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<div id="header-page">
  <div id="header" class ="container">
  <div id="logo">
    <h1>Header Logo</h1>
    </div>
    </div>  
  <div class="conntent">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/1351534443165528067/1637702650/1500x500" />
  </div>
    </div>
  
  <div id="threeColumns">
  <div id="column1">
    <h2> Column 1</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vulputate et libero at scelerisque. Suspendisse rhoncus tincidunt metus, ut cursus ipsum placerat venenatis. Nullam neque nisl, rhoncus at est quis, faucibus faucibus neque.</p> 
    </div>
    <div id="column2">
    <h2> Column 2</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vulputate et libero at scelerisque. Suspendisse rhoncus tincidunt metus, ut cursus ipsum placerat venenatis. Nullam neque nisl, rhoncus at est quis, faucibus faucibus neque.</p> 
    </div>
    <div id="column3">
    <h2> Column 3</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vulputate et libero at scelerisque. Suspendisse rhoncus tincidunt metus, ut cursus ipsum placerat venenatis. Nullam neque nisl, rhoncus at est quis, faucibus faucibus neque.</p> 
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 h1{
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: "impact"
}
```

this works for me using your code provided.

[image: fixed]

Hope that helps!